# Hay alguna forma de paralizar momentaneamente un programa en c++?

Tags: c++, c++11

Estoy haciendo un programa en c++ , sobre un juego de hacer cafe, en el cual quiero paralizar unos segundos la pantalla para que se lea lo que se imprime, sin necesidad de colocar algo como "tecle cualquier cosa para continuar" y mandarle un cin>>, se puede o existe alguna libreria que incluya esto?

Answer (score 0):

claro, puedes utilizar un `system("pause");` en caso de que estés programando en consola. si estás utilizando alguna librería de gráficos, puedes utilizar algún `delay(tiempo en milisegundos);` o un `sleep(tiempo en segundos);`
estas son cosas que yo he usado en mi poco tiempo como programador y que me han servido bastante

Comment: Aaa ssisisi, este, sabes si hay alguna forma de pausarlo con el system pause, y cambiar o quitar la frase de "tecle algo para continuar"?